# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity

Tags: mathematics, notation, real-analysis

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit) Bolzano and later Weierstrass were the first who gave an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity and convergence.
But did they already use the letters $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ in their formulation and, if yes, did they have any particular reason for their choice?

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the *use* of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ in the context of the definition of continuity of *functions*, we can say that they "were in the air" since Cauchy.

See [Augustin-Louis Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustin-Louis_Cauchy)'s definition of *limit* in terms of *infinitesimals* in his [Cours d'Analyse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cours_d%27Analyse) (1821):

- Robert Bradley & C.Edward Sandifer (editors), [Cauchy's Cours d’analyse : An Annotated Translation](https://books.google.it/books?id=M0or-HGe7D0C&pg=PA21) (2009).

As we can see, the definition is purely "verbal".

See [page 26](https://books.google.it/books?id=M0or-HGe7D0C&pg=PA26) for *continuity* :

> Let $f(x)$ be a function of the variable $x$, and suppose that for each value of $x$ between two given limits [i.e. in an *interval* $[x_0,x_1]$], the function always takes a unique finite value. If, beginning with a value of $x$ contained between these limits, we add to the variable $x$ an infinitely small increment $\alpha$, the function itself is incremented by the difference
>
> $$f(x+\alpha)− f(x),$$
>
> which depends both on the new variable a and on the value of $x$. Given this, the function $f(x)$ is a continuous function of $x$ between the assigned limits if, for each value of $x$ between these limits, the numerical value of the difference
>
> $$f(x+\alpha)− f(x)$$
>
> decreases indefinitely with the numerical value of $\alpha$. In other words, *the function $f(x)$ is continuous with respect to $x$ between the given limits if, between these limits, an infinitely small increment in the variable always produces an infinitely small increment in the function itself*.

We can see in [page 22](https://books.google.it/books?id=M0or-HGe7D0C&pg=PA22), in the context of the discussion about *infinitely small and infinitely large quantities*, usually denoted with $\alpha$ :

> if $k$ denotes a finite quantity different from zero and $\epsilon$ denotes a variable number that decreases indefinitely with the numerical value of $\alpha$, the general form of infinitely small quantities of the first order is
>
> $$k \alpha \ \text {or at least} \ k \alpha (1 ± \epsilon).$$

---

Regarding $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ occurrences, see  A.-L.Cauchy, *Résumé des leçons données à l’école royale polytechnique sur le calcul infinitésimal*, Paris, 1823; in Oeuvres, series 2, vol.4, [page 44](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k90196z/f47) :

> If $f$ is a *continuous* function between the limits $x=x_0$ and $x=X$ [...].
>
> Let $\delta, \epsilon$ be two very small numbers, the first is chosen so that for all numerical values of $i$ less than $\delta$ and for any value of $x$ between the limits $x_0, X$, the ratio
>
> $$\frac {f(x+i)− f(x)}{i}$$
>
> will always be greater than $f'(x) - \epsilon$ and lesser than $f'(x) + \epsilon$.

---

See also :

- Judith V.Grabiner, [Who Gave You the Epsilon? Cauchy and the Origins of Rigorous Calculus](http://www.mr-ideahamster.com/classes/assets/a_evepsilon.pdf), *The American Mathematical Monthly*, March 1983, Volume 90, Number 3, pp.185–194.

---

For [Bernard Bolzano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Bolzano), see the English translation (by S.B.Russ) of Bolzano's paper, [Rein analytischer Beweis des Lehrsatzes, dass zwischen je zwey Werthen, die ein entgegengesetzes Resultat gewähren, wenigstens eine reelle Wurzel der Gleichung liege](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0315086080900361) (Prague 1817), page 162 :

> According to a *correct definition*, the expression *that a function $fx$ varies according to the law of continuity for all values of $x$ inside or outside certain limits* means just that: if $x$ is some such value, the difference $f(x + \omega) - fx$ can be made smaller than any given quantity provided $\omega$ can be taken as small as we please.

---

See also :

- Gert Schubring, [Conflicts Between Generalization Rigor and Intuition in the Development of Analysis in 17th-19th Century France and Germany](https://books.google.it/books?id=rMWe3okqPOcC&pg=PA535) (2006), page 535, for another source : [Johann Georg Tralles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Georg_Tralles) (1763 – 1822).

In the manuscript “*On the founding of higher analysis*” to which is attached the note, “*Draft of Lecture* (dated 17.3.1808)”

> Tralles described discontinuity as a “jump” in the values of the function (Fol.
> 10v), but he also gave an algebraic description, in an early use of the letters $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ , by which he stated that “for however small a number $\delta$ of the radical $\Delta$” (he considers the function to be dependent on an increase $\Delta$) “and for the value $\alpha$ of the function corresponding to $\delta$ the inequality $\alpha^{\epsilon} > (1 - \omega)^{\epsilon}$ must hold” (Fol. 19v).

Comment: Mauro, it would be nice if you could make it clear that Cauchy never gave an epsilon-delta definition of continuity, but on the contrary gave an infinitesimal definition.  Namely, an infinitesimal $x$-increment always leads to an infinitesimal $y$-increment.

Comment: Mauro, describing Cauchy's definition of continuity as "verbal" is ambiguous. Taken literally this is not correct, since Cauchy does use formulas in his definition: for an infinitesimal $\alpha$, he requires $f(x+\alpha)-f(x)$ to be infinitesimal. So this definition is not "purely verbal" since it uses *formulas*. If what you mean is Grabiner's dichotomy of "verbal" definitions as opposed to epsilon-delta ones requiring alternating quantifiers, then it is of course true that the infinitesimal definition requires no alternating quantifiers. But that is its strength rather than weakness.

Comment: As far as Schubring's book is concerned, you don't do a stack exchange reader a service by citing it, as the book is profoundly flawed; see [this recent article](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/infinitesimals.html#17e). Specifically with regard to Cauchy, Schubring is particularly confused.

Answer (score 5):

See the answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82302/why-do-we-use-epsilon-and-delta. In particular, $\varepsilon$ is from the first letter of the French word "erreur" (error). Probably $\delta$ is from the first letter of the French word "différence."